# How to get unique and most popular values from PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the most popular and unique value from each array. I already have the means of tallying points for these objects in the arrays. Thinking these first 3 arrays as 'categories':
 (obviously example items)

```
$item1 = array( spoon => 5, knife => 3, fork => 2); 
$item2 = array( fork => 5, knife => 4, spoon => 2);
$item3 = array( spoon => 4, knife => 3, fork => 1);
```

That was the tally for each individual category. I then make a key_array for each category and another array consisting of the most popular from each.

```
$max1 = array_keys($item1);
$max2 = array_keys($item2);
$max3 = array_keys($item3);

$maxset = array( 0 => $max1[0], 1 => $max2[0], 2 => $max3[0]);
```

With the example, I have 2 spoons in `$maxset`. So now, I need to check for duplicates and choose the more popular one:

```
    foreach($maxset as $key => $value){
        $check = array();                                 
        if(in_array($value, $check)){
            $checkkey = array_search($value, $check);     //get key where $value already exists
            $checkval = ${'item' . $checkkey+1}[$value];  // get popularity of original copy
            $checkvalnew = ${'item' . $key+1}[$value];    // get popularity of duplicate

            if ($checkval > $checkvalnew){                // if the original is more popular
                $newvalue = ?;                    // ! 
                array_push($check, $newvalue);      
            }                   
            else{                                         // if the duplicate is more popular
                $check[$checkkey] = ?;            // !
                array_push($check, $value);
            }
        }else{
            array_push($check, $value);
        }
    }
```

Where it has a `'// !'`: I'm not sure what to do in here. If I get a new value, then what if it too is a duplicate? I'd need a function to check it, but then how would I not get stuck in a loop?

In the end, it should look like:

```
$check = array(0 => spoon, 1 => fork, 2 => knife); // it would be inserted into a database
```

Am I using the wrong method to achieve this? Is there, perhaps, a much more efficient language to do this task? Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** (Further example sets to determine formula) ** where answer should be selected

```
$item1 = array(red => 5, **green** => 4, yellow => 2, blue => 1);
$item2 = array(**blue** => 5, green => 3, red => 2, yelow => 1);
$item3 = array(**red** => 6, blue => 4, yellow => 2, green => 1);

$check = array(0 => green, 1 => blue, 2 => red)  // red1 got replaced by more popular red3
//Total point: 15


$item1 = array(yellow => 5, blue => 4, **red** => 2, green => 1);
$item2 = array(**blue** => 5, green => 3, red => 2, yellow => 1);
$item3 = array(**yellow** => 6, green => 4, red => 2, blue => 1);

$check = array(0 => red, 1 => blue, 2 => yellow)  // yellow1 got replaced by more popular yellow3. The replacement for yellow1 was blue1, which lost to blue2. 
//Total point: 13
```

Comment: seems like a homework assignment...

Comment: Nope. Just making a tool for my website. :) If it was homework that would be wrong of me to ask.

Comment: Thanks for that edit by the way!

Comment: Last example, $item1 has the key "blue" twice! $item2 has "yelow" instead of "yellow"

Comment: Sorry. You get what I'm asking though, right?

Comment: In your edited example why isn't green mentioned in the second set of arrays?

Comment: @Eliel, what do you mean? Why is it not in the answer?

Comment: It's not in the check array because it shouldn't be. Green wasn't a popular color in each of the categories. Since yellows were duplicate, one needed to be replaced. The one that was less popular (the yellow from $item1 in Edit Example 2's case) lost and the next more popular, that wasn't a duplicate, was red. Green wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a new answer, as the OQ has changed quite heavily.

What you now do, is to consider `$item1`, `$item2` and `$item3` not as hierarchical, but as equals - you take the highest value from **any** `$itemX`, then dismiss this category and value, repeat twice. So let's do this!

First step: We need a function, that finds the max value in a 2D structure, then removes the row and column where it was found from the structure, giving back row and column.

```
function reduce(&$items) {

    //Find max value and coordinates
    $item=false;
    $key=false;
    $value=0;
    foreach ($items as $i=>$a)
        foreach ($a as $k=>$v)
            if ($v>$value) {
                $item=$i;
                $key=$k;
                $value=$v;
            }

    //Unset used coordinates
    unset($items[$item]);
    foreach ($items as $i=>$a)
        if (isset($a[$key])) unset($items[$i][$key]);

    //return found item
    return array($item, $key);
}
```

Second Step: Initialize everything and call function three times, then clean up

```
$items=array($item1, $item2, $item3);
$maxset=array();

$reduce=reduce($items);
$maxset[$reduce[0]]=$reduce[1];
$reduce=reduce($items);
$maxset[$reduce[0]]=$reduce[1];
$reduce=reduce($items);
$maxset[$reduce[0]]=$reduce[1];

ksort($maxset);
print_r($maxset);
```

This was verified with all your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Also, I realize that making another array for each specific value and list which category it appears, and sorted by popularity MIGHT also work.

Answer (score 2):

We have two distinct steps:

- Sort by popularity
- Keep unique

Let's tackle it this way!

```
//Step 1: Sort by popularity and dismiss values
arsort($item1, SORT_NUMERIC);
$item1=array_keys($item1);
arsort($item2, SORT_NUMERIC);
$item2=array_keys($item2);
arsort($item3, SORT_NUMERIC);
$item3=array_keys($item3);

//Step 2: Keep unique
//2a: $item1 has highest priority
$maxset=array($item1[0]);
//2b: Walk $item2 until we find an unused value
foreach ($item2 as $item)
  if (!in_array($item, $maxset)) {
    $maxset[]=$item;
    break;
  }
//2c: Walk $item3 until we find an unused value
foreach ($item3 as $item)
  if (!in_array($item, $maxset)) {
    $maxset[]=$item;
    break;
  }
```

After discussion in the comments, it turns out the question is to be read differently. Here is an adapted solution:

```
//Step 1: Collaps the three items into one array
$maxset=array()
foreach ($item1 as $k=>$v)
  if (!isset($maxset[$k])) 
    $maxset[$k]=$v;
  //Uncomment one of the following lines, depending
  //on whether you want sum or max of popularity
  // else if ($maxset[$k]<$v) $maxset[$k]=$v;
  // else $maxset[$k]+=$v;


//Step 2: Sort by popularity and dismiss values
arsort($maxset, SORT_NUMERIC);
$maxset=array_keys($maxset);

//Step 3: Cut to three items
$maxset=array_slice($maxset, 0, 3);
```

Comment: As far as I understand the question this will not solve it the right way. If spoon in item1 were 4 and spoon in item3 were 5, you should have kept spoon in item3, because it is more popular. But maybe I mistunderstood.

Comment: Thanks RST, was just about to write that, actually. Thanks Eugen for making me think of using foreach in every category. Didn't dawn on me until now.

Comment: @RST - I am quite sure, this is not the case: In the OQ's example, he takes `knife` from 3, not from 2

Comment: @Eugen Rieck, I took knife as 3 because spoon was already taken in category 1. Being that the spoon in category 3 was less popular, I moved to the next value, which was knife.

Comment: @Kragalon - you should update your question with a better example. So we must chose the three top values, no matter in which `$itemX` they are?

Comment: No, it matters what category they are in. I guess I'm looking to get the most points, or tallies, while having no duplicate objects. So in my example, the winner would have a total of 13 points and consist of objects (spoon > fork > knife). I realize that the array of `$item1` coincidentally matches the answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, so you are searching for the tuple `($item1[$index1], $item2[$index2], $item3[$index3])` that has the highest sum of points of all tuples?

Comment: Not necessarily, the points are a way to reword it. The first version of your answer looks more efficient, but I still need the method on how to replace duplicates with the next unused object.

Comment: The first method will not create duplicates!

Comment: I edited my question with more examples. If those examples were passed in your answers's code, they wouldn't yield the same result. Indeed, they would be unique, but not most popular. It would pass `$item1[0]` through and never make a motion to correct it with the more popular alternative. That's the part I'm missing in my original question. If your code was passed in my other example sets, it would yield: `array(red, blue, yellow)` and `array(yellow, blue, green)` because it is giving the previous arrays a higher priority. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score -1):

**I had to replace my entire answer with the following. Is this close to what you're trying to achieve?**

Steps taken

1. Create our arrays
2. Merge our arrays into one so that we can loop through it easily
3. Merge our arrays and get a unique set of keys (ex. red, green, yellow, blue, orange)
4. Loop through our giant array and access them separately (ex. item1, item2, item3)
5. Categorize our points into a list specifically for that category/color (ex. red => 5, 2, 6)
6. Get the highest or most popular number within that category and place it into our `$check` array
7. Our `$check` array should now hold the highest values for each category
8. Use `array_sum` to get the total number of points.

   ```
   // Our arrays - notice i placed orange just to show how all the keys are merged

   $item1 = array('red' => 5, 'green' => 4, 'yellow' => 2, 'blue' => 1);
   $item2 = array('blue' => 5, 'green' => 3, 'red' => 2, 'yellow' => 1);
   $item3 = array('red' => 6, 'blue' => 4, 'yellow' => 2, 'green' => 1, 'orange' => 1);

   $items = array();
   $final = array();

   $items[] = $item1;
   $items[] = $item2;
   $items[] = $item3;

   // Grab a list of keys from our multiple arrays
   $item_keys = array_keys(array_merge($item1, $item2, $item3));

   /*
   var_dump($item_keys); // Produces the following:

   array(5) {
       [0]=> string(3) "red"
       [1]=> string(5) "green"
       [2]=> string(6) "yellow"
       [3]=> string(4) "blue"
       [4]=> string(6) "orange"
   }

   */

   foreach( $items as $sub )
   {

       foreach( $sub as $category => $points ) {

           foreach( $item_keys as $key ) {

               // Sort the points within that category
               if ( $key == $category ) {

                   $final[$category][] = $points;

                   // Grab the highest or most popular category/point?
                   $check[$category] = max($final[$category]);

               }

           }

       }

   }

   // sort by popularity
   arsort($check, SORT_NUMERIC);

   /*
   var_dump($check); // Produces the following:

   array(5) {
       ["red"]=> int(6)
       ["blue"]=> int(5)
       ["green"]=> int(4)
       ["yellow"]=> int(2)
       ["orange"]=> int(1)
   }

   */

   // total points = 18
   var_dump(array_sum($check));
   ```